Which 2D-graphics fighting game first introduced four-way 3D movement?
Early 3D-graphics fighting games like Virtua Fighter and Tekken allowed four-way movement where players could move their characters forward, backward, and sidestep left or right, adding a new layer of strategy to combat. This was a significant departure from traditional 2D fighting games, where lateral movement was typically impossible.
I'm curious which 2D-graphics fighting game first managed to implement this four-way 3D-style movement. These games might have used different sprites to represent various angles, creating the illusion of 3D space.
A Reddit comment suggests that Dark Edge, released by Sega in 1993, might be the first such game. According to the Sega Wiki:

Dark Edge is a fighting game with a twist. Not only can players fight each other on a horizontal plane, but they can enter the background and foreground, allowing eight directions to fight from.




However, I'm unsure if there are any earlier examples of 2D fighting games with four-way 3D movement. Does anyone know of a game that predates Dark Edge in implementing this feature?
Which fighting game was the first to implement four-way 3D movement while using 2D graphics?
To clarify, I'm specifically looking at one-on-one fighting games, not beat 'em up games that involve fighting multiple computer-controlled enemies simultaneously, nor mini-games in non-fighting games.

Would games like Double Dragon, Pit Fighter and Streets Of Rage count? Also, I recall Ballz as having 3D movement and scaling while composing the characters entirely out of, well, balls.

@user25730 Interesting examples, but they're not quite what I'm after. I'm specifically looking at one-on-one fighting games, not beat 'em ups, which involve fighting multiple computer-controlled enemies at once.

@user25730 Pit Fighter seems to be fighting game, but I'm not sure if it actually allows for 3D movement.

I am starting to wonder if Punch Out does indeed technically fit your requirements :P

@SPArcheon-onstrike Punch-Out is an interesting case! It's more of a rhythm game than a traditional fighting game, though, and doesn't have the free 3D movement I'm after.

Left you some messages in the chat to avoid encumbering the comment section.
